# Definition: Using positional arguments when initializing function

Tags: python, function

I am looking for the name of the process where you call a function using param=. For example:

```
class Test:
    def __init__():
        pass

    def testing(arg1):
        return solution = arg1 + arg1

t = Test()
t.testing(arg1=4)
```

What is the process called used in the last line where I *explicit* set each param manually?

Comment: Are you referring to "keyword arguments"?

Comment: As an aside, the code shown here is broken (`=` cannot be part of an expression, and even with `:=`, parentheses would be required, and it would also be pointless in a `return` statement), and there is no reason to use a class here. (Also, that's *explicit*, not implicit.)

Comment: Side-note: This code is syntactically invalid (you can't use an assignment statement inside a `return` statement) and illegal in other ways (`t.testing(arg1=4)` will pass a `self` argument implicitly, and `testing` doesn't accept it).

Comment: ShadowRanger : You are correct, I quickly wrote the code. Thank you! @Karl Knechtel : I learned about classes today and felt cool so I wrote it this way but understood. Ian Shelvinton Yes, this is what I couldn't remember